# Why is the 2nd approach is incorrect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

**Question:** A particle is thrown upwards from the ground. It experiences a constant air resistance which can produce a retardation of $2 \, \text{m/s}^2$ opposite to the direction of velocity of the particle. The ratio of the time of ascent to the time of descent is $\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers. Find the value of $\alpha + \beta$.

To solve this question, I used two approaches:

**First Approach:**

We know that $a=\frac{v-u}{t}$, which implies that $12\sqrt{\alpha} = u$ (where $u$ denotes the initial velocity with which the particle is thrown upwards). Substituting this value into $s = ut + \frac{1}{2} at^2$, we get $-s=-12\alpha + 6\alpha$. This implies that $s = 6\alpha$. Again, from $s = ut + \frac{1}{2} at^2$, we get $s = 4\beta$. Therefore, $4\beta = 6\alpha$ or $2\beta = 3\alpha$.

**Second Approach:**

We know that $a = \frac{v-u}{t}$. Thus, $12\sqrt{\alpha} = u$. Again, according to the question, $8\sqrt{\beta} = u$. Equating them, we get $3\sqrt{\alpha} = 2\sqrt{\beta}$.

According to the given solution in my book, $3\alpha = 2\beta$ is correct and not $3\sqrt{\alpha} = 2\sqrt{\beta}$.

Why am I getting two different equations? What is happening?

Edit: This is maybe a stupid question.But I am unable to see the error even after a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second approach you have implicitly assumed that after the object has fallen for a time $\sqrt \beta$ it has speed $u$ i.e. you are assuming that its speed profile as it descends is the reverse of its speed profile as it ascends. This is incorrect because its deceleration as it ascends is $12 \space m/s^2$ whereas its acceleration as it descends is only $8 \space m/s^2$.

Comment: Damn! Thanks! This didn't come to my mind